# Basic jquery function not being triggered in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I cannot get a basic jQuery function to work in my Rails app.  I've put the following code into users.js

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("a").click(function(event){
       alert("hi");
       event.preventDefault();
     });
   });
```

When I view the source code of a page, it contains users.js which contains this function, but clicking links does not cause the alert to show up.  Even if I switch to a simpler function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   alert("hi");
});
```

the alert still doesn't show up.  What's stranger, there is already functional javascript in this app.  If I copy either of the above to home.js, which contains other javascript code, it works fine.  It's only if I create a new js file that it doesn't work.  Can anyone explain what's happening?

Comment: sounds like you don't have jquery on this page

Comment: How is your HTML created?  Are the `a` elements you're expecting that event to be wired up to dynamically created?  Try changing your wire up to using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  `$('body').on('click', 'a', function(event) { ... });`

Comment: Gromer, I'll try that if I can get basic jQuery to work but I can't even get a basic alert to show up.  The HTML is a standard html.erb file with a layout.  Kalpaitch, the jQuery source is placed in the HTML via the asset pipeline.  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> shows up when I view source in my browser.  Note there is already javascript working on the page, and if I copy the code into a different javascript file (in this case, home.js) it works.  It's only when I keep it in user.js that the js isn't activated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fixed this error, but I didn't debug the problem correctly before coming onto StackOverflow.  I need to read up on the asset pipeline some more before fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of your page and try man `:)` simple demo with script added: http://jsfiddle.net/vdLU7/

Seems you are missing the JQ source, hope it fits the cause!

**Script**

```
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>
```

Comment: I have the jQuery source loaded via a rubygem.  If I right click the source code of the page, it shows: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in the head of the html document

Comment: @JazearBrooks try this as well, gems might be acting funny! do you have any trusted link I can see your code? lemme know! `:)` **oh** whats that semi column ? in your script?

Comment: I'd like to send you a link Tats_innit, but I don't see a way to send private messages on StackOverflow